# A facebook pop up widget code conflicts with other content (ajax tabs dynamic output)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hello after inserting the following code to display facebook pop-up widget inside a tpl file, i had a problem with other content that's not working after inserting this widget
I think the jquery.min.js once added to the body of document with the widget that's makes the problem occurs(i have another one included in the header dynamic file,but the widget doesn't appear only if i add it to the body of document-in my case footer.tpl/or detail.tpl)
 code:

**widget code**:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

{literal}

<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
jQuery.cookie = function (key, value, options) {

// key and at least value given, set cookie...
if (arguments.length > 1 && String(value) !== "[object Object]") {
options = jQuery.extend({}, options);

if (value === null || value === undefined) {
options.expires = -1;
}

if (typeof options.expires === 'number') {
var days = options.expires, t = options.expires = new Date();
t.setDate(t.getDate() + days);
}

value = String(value);

return (document.cookie = [
encodeURIComponent(key), '=',
options.raw ? value : encodeURIComponent(value),
options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
options.path ? '; path=' + options.path : '',
options.domain ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '',
options.secure ? '; secure' : ''
].join(''));
}

// key and possibly options given, get cookie...
options = value || {};
var result, decode = options.raw ? function (s) { return s; } : decodeURIComponent;
return (result = new RegExp('(?:^|; )' + encodeURIComponent(key) + '=([^;]*)').exec(document.cookie)) ? decode(result[1]) : null;
};
//]]>
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
if($.cookie('popup_user_login') != 'yes'){
$('#fanback').delay('0').fadeIn('medium');
$('#fanclose, #fan-exit').click(function(){
$('#fanback').stop().fadeOut('medium');
});
}
});
</script>{/literal}

<div id='fanback'>
<div id='fan-exit'>
</div>
<div id='fanbox'>
<div id='fanclose'>
</div>
<div class='remove-borda'>
</div>
<iframe allowtransparency='true' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' src='//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?

href=http://www.facebook.com/ethiobesttubefans&width=402&height=255&colorscheme=dark&show_faces=true&show_border=false&stream=false&header=false'

style='border: none; overflow: hidden; margin-top: -19px; width: 402px; height: 230px;'></iframe><center>
<span class="#h2_song" >Like Ethiobest Tube Community, Thanks!</span></center>
</div>
</div>
```

**The other content :(only this code is not giving its dynamic output ( it's using ajax tabs..)**

```
                <div id="tabs_related" class="tabcontent">
                {$show_more_related}
                </div>

                <div id="tabs_sameartist" class="tabcontent">
                {$show_more_artist}
                </div>

                <div id="tabs_other" class="tabcontent">
                {$show_more_best}
                </div>

          </div>
        </div>
```

Ajax.php code (related php code):

```
case 'detail':

        $video_id   = $_GET['vid'];
        $video_id   = str_replace($illegal_chars, "", $video_id);
        $video      = request_video($video_id, '', true);
        $embed_code = '';

        if ( ! is_array($video))
        {
            exit();
        }

        switch ($action)
        {
            case 'show_more_best':

                $output =  show_more('best_in_category', $video['category'], 10);

            break;

            case 'show_more_artist':

                $output = show_more('same_artist', $video['artist'], 10);

            break;

            case 'show_more_related':

                $output = show_more('related', $video['category'], 10);

            break;
        }

        echo $output;
    break;

    default:
        exit();
    break;
}   //  end switch ($page)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function ($) { jquery code here});
```

This must stop conflict with jquery and ajax.